# 3D model with errors when exporting to Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura, 3d-models, blender

I 3D modeled a cartoon car using Blender, mostly using add and subtract with boolean tools. When I export to Ultimaker Cura, I get these cuts along the model. Does anyone know why this is happening? Appreciate any feedback on the model.

[image]

[image]

The blender file: https://github.com/dantedaiki/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/Cartoon%20Car.blend

Comment: That is not uncommon for Blender created files, look into [these questions](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender). It probablyhas something to do with the normals of the surfaces being inconsistent, an online STL fixing utility like [NetFabb](https://service.netfabb.com/login.php) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In blender, you can occasionally have faces with flipped normals. Those areas then are "inside out". Such areas are just ignored in Cura. Fixing the files is as simple as recalculating the normals, but you'd best use a program like [NetFabb](https://service.netfabb.com/login.php) for for that.